# ios simulator window scale/zoom

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, scale, simulator

- I am writing an iOS app
- I use Xcode 6.1 and I have iPhone 5 with ios version 8.1.2
- App tests fine with both simulator and device

I have observed with iPhone5 testing, sometimes app views correct on simulator but not device. I had to fix issues for device

Now I was trying to test with other versions. Since I dont have other devices, I use Simulator for other versions, 4s, 5s 6 plus etc.

I have few questions

- Which scale I sld be using to simulate device.

  - For eg. if I use scale 100% with **6plus**, then I need to scroll view but if I use 50% then I dont need to scroll
- Which zoom should I be using to get closer to device.

Also, my concern is since I used latest xCode and iOS versions for development, I might have used features that were not supported with older versions.

**Would simulator testing ensure that if it works for 4s simulator, then it will work for 4s device as well?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoom within the simulator affects only the mapping between simulated pixels and screen pixels. The simulator renders exactly the same image, then how that is put onto your Mac's screen varies. If you set it so large that the window has to allow you to scroll then the window will allow you to scroll.

The 4s can run the latest version of iOS. So, no, simulating a 4s will not mean you are testing against an earlier version of iOS. The two things are completely unrelated.

Comment: To be clear, I assume if I use smaller zoom/scale combination on simulator and I get the view as expected (meaning no scrolling), then I can expect the correct/same behavior on the device as well...right?

Comment: @user2384694 yes. Technically Apple always says "don't just use the simulator, it may be incorrect" but on this stuff I've always known the simulator to be entirely reliable. It's definitely normal to do 99% of development against the simulator for layout issues and then just quickly confirm versus a real device at the end, rather than expecting ongoing or significant deviations.